# Showing $\{(z - 2, z + 2): z \in \mathbb Z\}$ is an open cover of $[-3, 3]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This example is given in my book without proof so I was trying to prove it for a bit now.

I tried this below.

By Archimedian, $\exists n \in \mathbb N, \ n > x + 2$ for $x \in [-3, 3]. $Then $n + 2 > x$. This won't work as we want to show $z + 2 > x, \ z \in \mathbb Z.$

Next, the length of $[-3, 3]$ is $|-3 - 3| = |-6| = 6$ and the length of $(z - 2, z+ 2)$ is $|z - 2 - z - 2| = |-4| = 4$ and so $[-3, 3]$ doesn't fit inside $(z - 2, z+ 2)$ meaning we can't show $x \in [-3, 3] \implies \ x \in (z - 2, z+ 2) \implies \ x \in \bigcup (z - 2, z+ 2)$. But then it's not hard to prove $\mathbb R \subset (-n, n), \ n  \in \mathbb N.$ By Archimedian, $\forall r \in \mathbb R \ \exists n \in \mathbb N, \ n > r$. Then $-n < - r.$ Thus $-n < -r < r < n$ and so $r \in (-n, n).$ This works even though, $|\mathbb R| > |(-n, n)| (maybe).$

Only thing I can think of is to actually construct overlapping sets $S_i$ for certain values of $z \in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $[-3, 3] \subset \bigcup S_i.$

Is there a better, elegant proof for this statement?

Comment: "Only thing I can think of is to actually construct overlapping sets $S_i$ for certain values of $z \in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $[-3, 3] \subset \bigcup S_i.$" Yes. This is the way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you realize just how minimal and simple a statement that "such and such is an open cover" is.  It just means that so union of the sets contain the set.

$[-3, 3] \subset (-4,4)  = (-4,-2)\cup (-3,3)\cup.... (3,4) = \cup_{z\in\{-3,-2,...,1,2\}}\subset \{(z-2,z+2)|z\in \mathbb Z\}$.

"Only thing I can think of is to actually construct overlapping sets Si for certain values"

Why *wouldn't* you want to do that?  Doing such is *trivial* and obvious you do it by specifying the integers from $-3$ to $3$. Or simply claiming such a cover scans the entire reals (and so all subsets of the reals) because each interval overlaps both its successor and its predecessor.  That  *is* a complete and thorough proof.

Nothing more needs to be done.  This wasn't meant to be a noodle-scratcher.  It was meant to be any more than a statement like $(2,3) \subset (-5, 27)$.  It's meant to be self-evident.  You *can* prove it if you want but you really aren't expected to need to.

Answer (score 1):

Every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is at most $1/2$ away from an integer so the set covers all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: *at most $0.5$.